# Does marijuana inhibit cognitive functioning?

Tags: marijuana, brain-damage

There's a lot of conflicting information regarding this question and people have different agendas. I'm not a doctor, but from what I've read marijuana has been shown to inhibit healthy brain development in adolescents and lead to lower IQ scores. And although it's not nearly as addictive as opiates, like all other psychoactive drugs that work on the dopamine system there is the potential for psychological dependence.

However, my question relates to adults that use it responsibly. If one is over 25 (brain stops developing), active, and only uses marijuana occasionally without smoking is it unhealthy? Does it cause cognitive decline in that population? I think smoking all day, every day is a horrible way to live. Those people have long forgotten what it means to "feel their emotions." However, I'm still not sure whether it is considered unhealthy when used sensibly like the occasional glass of wine.

Comment: See the answer to this question, where the answer is no for someone over 21 years old,  https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/556/in-what-ways-do-studies-indicate-that-smoking-marijuana-is-detrimental-to-long-t?rq=1

Comment: But it should be over 25 years old considering the brain continues developing until then. Also, the link to that study expired. I would appreciate it if this question is left up because it is more specific than the other one.

Comment: Although the answer to the other question also answers this question, the two questions are not exact duplicates. Also, the other question is almost 4 years old so there may be newer information available.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Also, recreational marijuana laws are passing all over the country. There, this is a very relevant public health question that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Here's an insightful video I found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ts4Y4cHclas&list=LLTqJL26MHvbRem5Bb97nYAw&index=3&t=0s. However, if anyone has anything else to add I'd be interested in hearing.